# How to run a docker mongo?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a local mongod running where I developed my app.
Now i created a Mongo Docker Image and run the container.
I use docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Somehow my local mongo instance is always being used (probably because both are being accessed by localhost:27017). Only when i go to windows task manager and really kill the mongod instance, the docker mongo is used. What do i need to change to have both running?

Thanks!

Comment: Bind to another port? If you are after load balancing both simultaneously you need tcp proxy, like haproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the port 27017 to another port so that you can access the second instance on that port:

```
ports:
  - "27018:27017"
```

This exposes the docker internal port 27017 to your machine's 27018 port.

So your first local mongo instance will run on 27017 and this docker instance will run on 27018 (This can be any free port). Make sure no other local service is using this port.